# How to create very high resolution bitmaps in python?

Tags: python, bmp, python-imaging-library

Currently as per what I know the max resolution that can be created using pillow's image function is 3000*3000 but I need to create image which has resolution of 10000*10000 or more programmatically ???

If you people didn't get what I meant ,just comment to me rahter than closing this question (please)I will give a more detailed question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only ways to create a pixel-perfect SVG from a bitmap is to `<rect/>` elements for each pixel (or [block of same-colored pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)), or to use an `<image>` element to reference your bitmap. In neither case will you end up reducing the file size.

A vector format like SVG is not well-suited to representing hand-tweaked pixels. You likely want to use a bitmap format that supports lossless compression, such as PNG. If file size is of critical importance, you may wish to use a tool like [OptiPNG](http://optipng.sourceforge.net) to ensure that your PNG files are as small as possible.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz i think i can live with the <rect/> anyway thanks again